# How do I extract a maximum of 14 names out of a big list that, together, have all the letters of the alphabet?

Tags: python, list, loops, alphabet

I am a new programmer. As the title states, this is my attempt to get this done:

```py
def alphabet_set(countrylist):
    alphabetical_list = []
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   
    for country in countries:
        for i in country:
            if i in alphabet:
                alphabetical_list.append(country)
            if i == 26:
                break    
    return alphabetical_list

print(alphabet_set(countries))
```

Again, this list I am drawing from is BIG. I need 14 country names, that will give me all the letters of the alfabet. Alphabetical_list would be my list of 14 countries that contain all 26 letters of the alphabet.

Comment: you may find [`set()`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) help you!

Comment: How big can your list of country names be?  There are fewer than 300 possibilities right?

Comment: How would you do this given the countries all printed out on individual index cards?  Work that out then work out how to convert that to code!

Comment: An example approach would be, find a country with the most letters in the alphabet, add the country to the list and remove those letters from the alphabet and repeat until you run out of letters, or countries. This is quite inefficient but I think minimises the length of your list

Comment: these parable like examples I find confusing the question more

Comment: Why 14? Surely it can be done with fewer?

Comment: it doesn't matter how much to me, I need to know what direction to go in with the code

Comment: Could you provide the list of country names so we can actually test potential solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `set()`

```
def alphabet_set(countrylist:list[str]):
    alphabetical_list = []
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    countriescontains = []
    letters = set()
    for country in countrylist:
        if len(letters)==26 or len(alphabetical_list) == 14:break
        elif set(country.lower()).intersection(alphabet):
            alphabetical_list.append(country)
            print({x.lower() for x in country},letters.union({x.lower() for x in country}))
            letters=letters.union({x.lower() for x in country if x != ' '})
    print(sorted(list(letters)))
    
    return alphabetical_list
print(alphabet_set(countries))
```

this would decrease the complexity of `alphabet_set` from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, witch will be a massive improvement in terms of performance.

Comment: I think that only works if exactly one country has all letters, which isn't what they were asking.

Comment: i think i misunderstood, could you explain, so i can fix my answer?

Comment: I need the code to select 14 countries from a country list. Those 14 country names have to contain all 26 letters of the alphabet, so it's ok if you have 3 times the letter 'a' for example as long as the 14 country names will contain all 26 letters of alphabet

Comment: if i understood you this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the answer I came up with:

```
def alphabet_set(countries):   
    alphabetical_list = []
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for country in countries:
        for i in country:
            if i.lower() in alphabet and country not in alphabetical_list:
                alphabet = alphabet.replace(i.lower(),'')
                alphabetical_list.append(country)
            if alphabet == '':
                break    
    return alphabetical_list
print(alphabet_set(countries))
```